# Opening WebP image format in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webp

Is there anyway to open WebP images in windows phone applications? I have a huge set of images to be downloaded from the web and jpg/png are heavy, so looking for an image format that would reduce the data to be downloaded without compromising much on the quality.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommends you to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP#Criticism. Secondly, since the fact that WebP is a web standard for images, you can try using a WebBrowser as your image control.
Finally, I believe that the reason you cannot reduce the quality its because you want to use the same image as an thumbnail. I suggest you to create a process that will generate a thumbnail, something like 480px x 800px for example. Now your Windows Phone app can show a "preview" of the image, and if the user wants to see the full one, must wait.